# RewriteRule не работает

Tags: php, apache, joomla, apache2, mod-rewrite

хочу перенаправить страницу с урлом на другую, т.е. вывести на этой странице содержимое другой страницы (без редиректа). Но не могу понять, почему не срабатывает rewriterule.

Мой урл: site.ru/elektrovelosiped

Мой htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule elektrovеlosiped index.php?controller=category&task=view&category_id=30 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

Проверять нужно значение у `REQUEST_URI`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/elektrovеlosiped$
RewriteRule .* index.php?controller=category&task=view&category_id=30 [L,QSA]
```